# How to set default folder for ASP .NET Core Web Site?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I´m working with a simple ASP .NET Core website, in order to provide a host for an AngularJS app.

My folder structure is:

> /wwwroot/app/index.html

I have tried some configurations at the Startup.cs file, like this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot", "app"))
            });
```

But even with above configuration I still have to navigate to http://localhost:PORT/app in order to display my Index.html file.

I would like my Index.html be displayed when I navigate to the root address (http://localhost:PORT/)

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Just found the solution. Need to add this line at the *WebHostBuilder*:

```
    .UseWebRoot(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "app"))
```

Comment: Have you changed `.UseContentRoot(...)` in `program.cs`?

Comment: Hi, I also tried this, but still doesn´t works. `.UseContentRoot(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "app"))`